# AppleScript in automator error (“The action ”Run AppleScript“ encountered an error ”) again

Tags: applescript, automator

I was getting this error with a script wrote to on AirPlay.  The script ran as expected as I was creating it in the Automator App.  When I tried to run it as a service from another app, I received the error message above.

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "Displays")
        click menu item "Family Room Apple TV" of menu 1 of result
        delay 1
        click (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description contains "Displays")
        click menu item "Use As Separate Display" of menu 1 of result
        delay 5
    end tell
end tell
```

Works fine in automator. When I try to run it as a service: “The action ”Run AppleScript“ encountered an error."

I read about another user who was having a similar problem with another script.  The solution to his problem was to grant accessibility permission from the app he was using the service.  I remembered that as I was creating the script in automated i had to grant automated permission.  So, I granted permission to the Finder App.  Now it runs fine as a service from Finder. But I want this service to be able to run ANY time no matter what app is active. I certainly don't want to have to give permission to EVERY app on my MAC. I'm sure I am also missing something simple and dumb. Any Ideas?